# How to remove Letters AFTER-BEFORE specific Letters in dart

Tags: string, dart

i found here many question about How to remove Letters AFTER specific Letters but did not find AFTER-BEFORE specific Letters

i don't know if it possible in dart ..

sample

```
String test = 'HelloAflutterBHello'
```

so how to outputs the following result

```
print(test) => 'flutter'
```

that's mean i want to delete everything before ('A') and everything after ('B')

i tried this

```
print(test.substring(0, test.indexOf('B')));
```

but this will delete only anything after  ('B') but couldn't find a way to delete the Letters before ('A') too ..

i hope any good answer . thanks

Comment: `print(test.substring(test.indexOf('A') + 1, test.indexOf('B')));`  Assuming that there is exactly one occurrence of `'A'` and `'B'`.

Comment: wonder why this answer located as comment .. it is work thanks , but it is possible if they were group of specific letter like HelloABCflutterQMBHello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to do the job. This way you can check for more than one character.
Consider this code:

```dart
void main() {
String test = 'HelloABCflutterDEFHello';

//regex match all characters between two (or more) specified characters
RegExp exp = RegExp(r"(?<=ABC).*(?=DEF)"); 

//store all results from searching within a string.
Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(test);

// access the captured value
print(matches.first.group(0)); 
}
```